# How do I remove people graph from my worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

A user has accidentally clicked on something in excel, and a  people graph has showed up. I am able to select it, but I can't figure out how to remove it. Does anyone here have any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Not had this happen to me, but what about your backup?

Comment: @SolarMike I'd prefer not having to reenter data since the last backup, but that is an option, yes.

Comment: I sympathise with that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "**People Graph**" is an app available for free in the app store. Take a look at this hint: [How do I get rid of the people graph, there is no X?](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/de-DE/2a977a29-ca1f-4e44-a9ee-72bd0b1385aa/how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-people-graph-there-is-no-x?forum=excel)

> Hover the mouse over the outer edge of the people graph, so it changes
>   to a four point arrow. Click once. Now the app has a visible border
>   with resizing handles. You can hit the delete key on your keyboard to
>   delete the app.

... and this one:

> This was the winning suggestion.  Pressing the delete key alone did
>   nothing. But, hitting [F5 + SPECIAL\OBJECTS] then DELETE KEY got rid
>   of the intrusive graph.

Comment: Oh yeah, I had already looked at that, and it didn't work for me - however, after unprotecting the worksheet it *did* work. >_> The devil is in the details :P